# Why does my program stops before reading all its inputs, and prints strange numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

i wrote code that take integer and char in array from user then print it in screen,
but i had problem in the run,it just take two input and print strange numbers!, can any one know what is wrong .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
   const int size =3;
   int s_i[size];
   char s_n[size];
   int i,j;

   for( i=0;i<size;i++){
      cout<<"enter s_i"<<endl;
      cin>>s_i[i];
      cout<<"enter s_n"<<endl;
      cin>>s_n[i];
   }

   for (j=0;j<size;j++){
      cout<<s_i[j]<<s_n[j]<<endl;
   }

   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong.

Comment: @5gon12eder it is ugly sure, but why "wrong"? C++ does not have a clear definition of correct indentation

Comment: what is indentation ?

Comment: Add space between numbers: `out<<s_i[j]<<s_n[j]<<endl;` ==> `out<<s_i[j]<<" "<<s_n[j]<<endl;`

Comment: Apart from that, the program seems “correct” and does what I'd expect it to do. May it be that you're surprised that it doesn't put a space between the `s_i` and `s_n`s? Try adding some: `cout << s_i[j] << ", " << s_n[j] << endl;`.

Comment: No problem with your code. The problem with the way you enter data. Make sure to enter integer when you're asked to do so and so with the char.

Comment: @lejlot Please forgive me for my blunt statement just this one time. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The code looks fine, and runs as intended. Maybe you try to input a char when asked for number (s_i?)

#### correct input

```
enter s_i
1
enter s_n
d
enter s_i
3
enter s_n
g
enter s_i
4
enter s_n
q
1d
3g
4q
```

#### incorrect input

```
enter s_i
a
enter s_n
enter s_i
enter s_n
enter s_i
enter s_n
0
0
4196672
```

Answer (score -2):

I ran your code. It runs perfect as long as you enter integer for the integer array and character for the character array.

Also, please develop the habit of creating instances using new int[]. This can also be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Why would you use `new int[]` here? Honestly, I would just about never use it. If you don't know the number of items in advance, use a `std::vector<int>`. But if it's always three numbers, using a stack-based array is a perfectly valid option.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, and that second paragraph is awesomely bad advice. Don't `new` anything unless forced to.